# Can't access vector elements in a for loop

Tags: r

Let's say I have two vectors:

```
a1=c("a","b")
a2=c("x","y")
```

Now in a 'for' loop, I want to access the first element of each vector:

```
for(i in c(a1,a2)) {
    print(i[1]) 
    }
```

If I run the above code, I get:

```
[1] "a" 
[1] "b" 
[1] "x"
[1] "y"
```

But I just want:

```
[1] "a" 
[1] "x"
```

More surprisingly, if I want to access the second element:

```
for(i in c(a1,a2)) { 
    print(i[2]) 
    }
```

I get:

```
[1] "NA" 
[1] "NA" 
[1] "NA" 
[1] "NA"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `c(a1, a2) = c("a","b","x","y")` -- passing multiple atomic vectors to `c` causes them to get collapsed. Use `list(a1, a2)` in the loop instead.